# MongoDB Index on Embedded Fields

Tags: mongodb, indexing

This example is from the `MongoDB` documentation:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId(...),
    "name": "John Doe",
    "address": {
        "street": "Main",
        "zipcode": "53511",
        "state": "WI"
    }
}
```

You can create an index on the `address.zipcode` field, using the following specification:

```
db.people.createIndex( { "address.zipcode": 1 } )
```

Does it mean that only one John Doe could live for the zip code `53511`?

I'm a bit confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not - it merely means that queries of the form

```
 db.people.find({"address.zipcode": "12345"})
```

Will be able to use that index rather than scanning the whole collection.

If the index where a unique one then it would prevent reuse of that zipcode across the whole collection